# How can I replace the EventBus pattern with RxJava presenters?

Tags: android, system.reactive, rx-java, reactive-programming, reactivex

The `Controller` + `EventBus` pattern works very well in Android, but firing events everywhere gets really messy. If a controller gets asks to load the same data multiple times, it's easy to have it start loading the first time, and ignore subsequent requests while its loading, and start listening to future loading requests once it's done loading. How can I do this with RxJava (using MVP presenters?)

**Scenario**

I have a singleton `ColorModel` in my android app that loads my favorite color ([from multiple sources](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/06/22/loading-data-from-multiple-sources-with-rxjava/)), as an `Observable<String>` (String == hexcode).

My `ColorPresenter` hooks into the `ColorModel`, converting the `String` hexcode into a `Color` object that can be displayed in the `ColorView`.

These are the main pieces of my logic:

1. `Observable<String> getColor()` (from `ColorModel`)
2. `Observable<Color> getColorForView()` (from `ColorPresenter`)
3. `subscribe()` (in `ColorView`)

**Problems**

- #1 is created on every subscription. If I have multiple presenters calling #1, this is very wasteful. I don't want this step repeated (only initiated on the first call, then cached after).
- When I unsubscribe during `onStop()`, #2 gets cancelled (desired), but that unsubscription bubbles up to #1 being cancelled too (**not desired**).

Comment: You need to show us your code. Just describing it isn't enough.

Comment: Also the first problem really doesn't seem to be a big deal - just how computationally expensive is the observerable?

Comment: @Enigmativity pretend it's very computationally expensive (I'm not actually loading a favorite color, it is a simplified version)

Comment: Ok, you just now need to show us the real code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ConnectedObservables with a replay operator. See the accepted answer at [Single Observable with Multiple Subscribers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35951942/single-observable-with-multiple-subscribers).

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at operator [`cache`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#cache()). You can use it and store reference to observable somewhere (like in case of `ConnectableObservable`).

Be careful, cause you don't have an ability to unsubscribe from observable that was created with `cache` operator. But in your case that's what you want, because unsubscribing from #2 does not affect #1 lifecycle anymore.