# Single Observable with Multiple Subscribers

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I have an `Observable<<List<Foo>> getFoo()` that is created from a Retrofit Service and after calling the
`.getFoo()` method, I need to share it with Multiple Subscribers. Calling the `.share()` method though, it causes the Network Call to be re-executed. Replay Operator does not work either. I know that a potential solution might be `.cache()`, but I do not know why this behaviour is caused.

```
// Create an instance of our GitHub API interface.
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();

// Create a call instance for looking up Retrofit contributors.
Observable<List<Contributor>> testObservable = retrofit
        .create(GitHub.class)
        .contributors("square", "retrofit")
        .share();

Subscription subscription1 = testObservable
       .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Contributor>>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(List<Contributor> contributors) {
                System.out.println(contributors);
            }
         });

Subscription subscription2 = testObservable
        .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Contributor>>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(List<Contributor> contributors) {
                System.out.println(contributors + " -> 2");
            }
         });

subscription1.unsubscribe();
subscription2.unsubscribe();
```

The code above can reproduce the aforementioned behaviour. You can debug it and see that the Lists received belong to a different MemoryAddress.

I have also looked at ConnectableObservables as a potential solution, but this requires me carrying the original observable around, and calling `.connect()` each time I want to add a new Subscriber.

This kind of behaviour with the `.share()` was working fine till Retrofit 1.9. It stopped working on Retrofit 2 - beta. I have not yet tested it with the Retrofit 2 Release Version, that was released some hours ago.

EDIT: 01/02/2017

For future readers, I have written an article [here](https://medium.com/@p.tournaris/rxjava-one-observable-multiple-subscribers-7bf497646675#.rjwhxkjhp) explaining more about the case!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You seem to be (implicitly) casting your `ConnectedObservable` returned by `.share()` back into a normal `Observable`. You might want to read up on the difference between hot and cold observables.

Try

```
ConnectedObservable<List<Contributor>> testObservable = retrofit
        .create(GitHub.class)
        .contributors("square", "retrofit")
        .share();

Subscription subscription1 = testObservable
   .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Contributor>>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable throwable) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(List<Contributor> contributors) {
        System.out.println(contributors);
    }
});

Subscription subscription2 = testObservable
        .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Contributor>>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(List<Contributor> contributors) {
                System.out.println(contributors + " -> 2");
            }
        });

testObservable.connect();
subscription1.unsubscribe();
subscription2.unsubscribe();
```

Edit: You don't need to call `connect()` every time you want a new subscription you only need it to start up the observable. I suppose you could use `replay()` to make sure all subsequent subscribers get all items produced

```
ConnectedObservable<List<Contributor>> testObservable = retrofit
        .create(GitHub.class)
        .contributors("square", "retrofit")
        .share()
        .replay()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The thing is that I really want to avoid calling connect each time. Are you sure that the replay operator will work fine with this use case?

Comment: Actually I tested it and it worked. Thank you for your time and your reply. Just for the sake of the issue I have read the difference between the hot and cold observables but couldn't reproduce it with the Network calls with Retrofit. If i used an Observable.just() the share operator was working pretty fine.

Answer (score 44):

After checking back with RxJava developer Dávid Karnok I'd like to propose a full explanation of what was going on here.

`share()` is defined as `publish().refCount()`, i. e. the source `Observable` is first transformed to a `ConnectableObservable` by `publish()` but instead of having to call `connect()` "manually" that part is handled by `refCount()`. In particular, `refCount` will call `connect()` on the `ConnectableObservable` when it itself receives the first subscription; then, as long as there is at least one subscriber it will stay subscribed; and, finally, when the number of subscribers drops to 0 it will unsubscribe upwards. With *cold* `Observables`, like the ones returned by Retrofit, this will stop any running computations.

If, after one of these cycles another subscriber comes along, `refCount` will again call `connect` and thus trigger a new subscription to the source Observable. In this case, it will trigger another network request.

Now, this usually did not become apparent with Retrofit 1 (and indeed any version before [this commit](https://github.com/square/retrofit/commit/38ce2bee70342ac1ab08115d74802d3a54d85511)), because these older versions of Retrofit by default moved all network requests to another thread. This usually meant that all your `subscribe()` calls would happen while the first request/`Observable` was still running and therefore the new `Subscriber`s  would simply be added to the `refCount` and therefore would not trigger additional requests/`Observables`.

Newer versions of Retrofit, however, do not by default move the work to another thread anymore - you have to do that explicitly by calling, for example, `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`. If you don't, everything will just stay on the current thread, meaning that the second `subscribe()` will only happen after the first `Observable` has called `onCompleted` and therefore after all `Subscribers` have unsubscribed and everything is shut down. Now, as we saw in the first paragraph, when the second `subscribe()` is called, `share()` has no choice but to cause another `Subscription` to the source Observable and trigger another network request.

**So, to go back to the behavior you are used to from Retrofit 1, just add `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`.**

This should result in only network request being executed - most of the time. In principle though, you could still get multiple requests (and you always could have with Retrofit 1), but only if your network requests are extremely fast and/or the `subscribe()` calls happen with considerable delay, so that, again, the first request is finished when the second `subscribe()` happens.

Therefore, Dávid suggests to either use `cache()` (but it has the drawbacks you mentioned) or `replay().autoConnect()`. According to these [release notes](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/releases), `autoConnect` works like only the first half of `refCount`, or more precisely, it is

> similar in behavior to refCount(), except that it doesn't disconnect
>   when subscribers are lost.

This means the request would only be triggered when the first `subscribe()` happens but then all later `Subscriber`s would receive all emitted items, regardless of whether there were, at any time in between, 0 subscribers.

Comment: Thank you for your extended explanation. Will sure take it mind, although I am pretty sure now that i have some comfortable solutions in place for this issue :)

Comment: Great! I just wanted to add this explanation because `replay`, `share`, `publish`, etc. are complicated enough and it doesn't hurt to have detailed explanations of edge cases out there.

Comment: Great answer indeed :)