# RxJava share an Observable's emissions between multiple subscribers

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I have the following problem:

I have a observable that is doing some work, but other observables need the output of that observable to work. I have tried to subscribe several times on the same observable, but inside the log i see that the original observable is initiated multiple times.

thats my observable thats create the object:

```
Observable.create((Observable.OnSubscribe<Api>) subscriber -> {
            if (mApi == null) {
                //do some work
            }
            subscriber.onNext(mApi);
            subscriber.unsubscribe();
        })
```

thats my observable that needs the object

```
loadApi().flatMap(api -> api....()));
```

I'm using

```
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) observable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io()
```

on all observables.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understood your question correctly, but I figure you're looking for a way to share the emissions of an observable between several subscribers. There are several ways of doing this. For one, you could use a [Connectable Observable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/observables/ConnectableObservable.html) like so:

```
ConnectableObservable<Integer> obs = Observable.range(1,3).publish();
obs.subscribe(item -> System.out.println("Sub A: " + item));
obs.subscribe(item -> System.out.println("Sub B: " + item));
obs.connect(); //Now the source observable starts emitting items
```

Output:

```
Sub A: 1
Sub B: 1
Sub A: 2
Sub B: 2
Sub A: 3
Sub B: 3
```

Alternatively, you could use a [PublishSubject](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/PublishSubject.html):

```
PublishSubject<Integer> subject = PublishSubject.create(); //Create a publish subject
subject.subscribe(item -> System.out.println("Sub A: " + item)); //Subscribe both subscribers on the publish subject
subject.subscribe(item -> System.out.println("Sub B: " + item));    
Observable.range(1,3).subscribe(subject); //Subscribe the subject on the source observable
```

Output:

```
Sub A: 1
Sub B: 1
Sub A: 2
Sub B: 2
Sub A: 3
Sub B: 3
```

Both of these examples are single threaded, but you can easily add observeOn or subscirbeOn calls to make them async.

Comment: yes i want the first result from the observable on every subscribe

Comment: what i should do when i don´t know how often my observable will be subscribed and when the subscriber should get the result before all are subscribed

Comment: This is pretty much answered in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35951942/single-observable-with-multiple-subscribers)

Comment: It wasn't related to my problem, but actually it is nice and simple :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all using Observable.create is tricky and easy to get wrong. You need something like

```
Observable.create(subscriber -> {
        if (mApi == null) {
            //do some work
        }
        if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
           subscriber.onNext(mApi);
           subscriber.onCompleted();
           // Not subscriber.unsubscribe(); 
        }            
 })
```

You can use

```
ConnectableObservable<Integer> obs = Observable.just(1).replay(1).autoConnect();
```

All subsequent subscribers should get the single emitted item

```
obs.subscribe(item -> System.out.println("Sub 1 " + item));
obs.subscribe(item -> System.out.println("Sub 2 " + item));
obs.subscribe(item -> System.out.println("Sub 3 " + item));
obs.subscribe(item -> System.out.println("Sub 4 " + item));
```

Comment: i have tried yours, but the on subscribe doesn´t get called. My observable is public static final.

Comment: Have you tried your original observable with the .publish().replay().autoconnect()?

Comment: I might have messed up the order of the operators. It should probably be .publish().autoconnect().replay(1). The share operator is equivalent to publish().refcount().