# Why does only the latest Subscriber get onNext Event in RxJava on Android using Kotlin and RxMVP

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, android-mvp, rx-binding

Given following scenario:

A `View` featuring a `CheckBox` and multiple `EditText`s
The `View` offers access to the `Observables` using [Jake Wharton's RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding) like so

```
fun observeUsername(): InitialValueObservable<CharSequence> = RxTextView.textChanges(et_username)
```

for the `EditText`s (there three of them, for Username, Password and Email) and

```
fun observeSignUpCheckBox(): InitialValueObservable<Boolean> = RxCompoundButton.checkedChanges(cb_sign_up)
```

for the `CheckBox`

The `Presenter` features one method per `EditText` which is as simple as

```
fun observeUsernameText(): Disposable {
    return view.observeUsernameText()
            .skipInitialValue()
            .map { username -> StringUtils.isValidUsername(username.toString()) }
            .subscribe({ view.setValidUsername(it) })
}
```

and one method for the `CheckBox`:

```
fun observeSignUpCheckBox(): Disposable {
    return view.observeSignUpCheckBox()
            .subscribe({ checked ->
                Timber.d("### view trigger")
            })
}
```

all of these methods are called in the `onCreate` of the `Presenter` and everything worked as expected.

**Now the Problem:**
I added a new function in the `Presenter` that validates the users input:

```
fun observeInputFields(): Disposable {
    val email = view.observeEmailText().map { email -> StringUtils.isValidEmail(email.toString()) }
    val password = view.observePasswordText().map { password -> StringUtils.isValidPassword(password.toString()) }
    val signUp = view.observeSignUpCheckBox()
    val username = view.observeUsernameText().map { username -> StringUtils.isValidUsername(username.toString()) }
    return Observable.combineLatest(email, password, signUp, username,
            Function4<Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean> { validEmail, validPassword, signUpChecked, validUsername ->
                validEmail && validPassword && (!signUpChecked || signUpChecked && validUsername)
            })
            .subscribe({ validForm ->
                Timber.d("### form trigger")
                view.enableContinue(validForm)
            })
}
```

Whenever I change the content of an `EditText` both `Subscriptions` (the one for the `EditText` and the combined one added in `observeInputFields`) receive the event as expected.
But, if I tap on the `CheckBox` **only the last `Subscription` receives the event** depending on the order of the functions in the `onCreate`.

```
fun onCreate() {
    // here the logs only show '### form trigger'
    disposables.add(observeSignUpCheckBox())
    disposables.add(observeInputFields())
    // ... omitted for clarity
}
```

or

```
fun onCreate() {
    // here the logs only show '### view trigger'
    disposables.add(observeInputFields())
    disposables.add(observeSignUpCheckBox())
    // ... omitted for clarity
}
```

I cannot figure out why this strange thing is happening only for the `CheckBox` but not for the `EditText`s. This is highly confusing...

Any help is greatly appreciated as I am currently stuck on this :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the source code of the library [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/blob/master/rxbinding/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/rxbinding2/widget/RxCompoundButton.java) and [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/blob/master/rxbinding/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/rxbinding2/widget/RxTextView.java), you will see that what you are describing is expected behaviour. For a`CompoundButton` you can have only one `Observable` at a time but for a`TextView` multiple.

If you want to go even further you can see that [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/blob/master/rxbinding/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/rxbinding2/widget/CompoundButtonCheckedChangeObservable.java) to create the `Observable` you need to use the `setOnCheckedChangeListener` on the `CompoundButton` which replaces the possible existing listener every time.

On the other hand, for `TextView` you can add multiple `TextWatchers` and remove each one individually `onDispose`.

Comment: You know, now that you've explained it, it makes perfect sense. I did read the documentation where it sais *Only one observable can be used for a view at a time.* but since I'm fairly new to RX I didn't realize that I'm using multiple Observables. I thought by subscribing to one I always get a reference to the same?! Now, is there an elegant way around this fact!

Comment: You would have to share the emissions of the Observable using a `ConnectableObservable` for example. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36810321/6774854)

Comment: Thanks @masp! What I did now: 1. I changed the **View** method to *fun observeSignUpCheckBox(): ConnectableObservable<Boolean> = RxCompoundButton.checkedChanges(cb_sign_up).publish()*, 2. the **Presenter** got a new member: *val signUpConnectable: ConnectableObservable<Boolean> by lazy { view.observeSignUpCheckBox() }* and 3. in the *onCreate()* of the **Presenter** I added *signUpConnectable.connect()* as last line. This seem works. Any recommendations here or it that fine?

Comment: Don't forget that `signUpConnectable.connect` returns a `disposable`. It needs to be taken care of.

Comment: You got it! Changed the *onCreate()* method to *disposables.add(signUpConnectable.connect())*  Thanks!