# Use concat() and first() to implement a cache with RxJava - concurrent calls

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I'm using RxJava and the `concat()` and `first()` operators:

```
public Observable<List<Entity>> getEntities() {
    invalidateCacheIfNeeded();
    return Observable
            .concat(cachedEntities(), networkEntities())
            .first();
}
```

The `cachedEntities` returns an Observable built from a cached list while the `networkEntities` method fetches the entities with Retrofit.

This works great unless two user subscribes quickly to the observables returned by `getEntities()`. I guess the network request of the first subscribe is not finished when the second subscribe is made. In this case, two network requests are performed. Which I want to avoid.

I tried to create a single thread Scheduler so the the execution of the second call is only carried out when the first call is over but with no luck:

```
 mSingleThreadScheduler = Schedulers.from(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
```

and:

```
public Observable<List<Entity>> getEntities() {
    invalidateCacheIfNeeded();
    return Observable
            .concat(cachedEntities(), networkEntities())
            .subscribeOn(mSingleThreadScheduler)
            .first();
}
```

I've tried to sprinkle the `subscribeOn` call lower in the Observable chain but I get the same result.

Any hint?

Comment: I believe you could simply use the `synchronized` keyword on your `getEntities()` declaration for your method and it should wait for a previous call to complete before allowing for another with a thread lock.

Comment: The `concat()` call is not blocking so `getEntities`returns almost immediatly. `synchronized` on the method won't work in this case.

Comment: But even if `concat()` is not blocking, whatever is calling `getEntities()` would be blocking while waiting for a return from the call wouldn't it?  So you would think `synchronized` would be ok for this call if you were trying to keep it from being called multiple times.  Unless I am missing something. How can it return immediately if it isn't finished its task?  Maybe I can pick up a tidbit here.

Comment: The `getEntities()` only build the Observabl (which is super fast). The real work is done when someone *subscribes* to this observable. But you're right my wording is probably misleading. I'll update the question to reflect the subscribing phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given

```
public Observable<List<Entity>> getEntities() {
    invalidateCacheIfNeeded();
    return Observable
            .concat(cachedEntities(), networkEntities())
            .first();
}
```

You should create an `AsyncSubject<Data> mSubject` and use it as follow

```
private Observable<List<Entity>> networkEntities() {
    return mSubject
            .map(Data::getEntities);
}
```

And your network call should look like this

```
public Observable<Data> getDataFromNetwork() {
    return networkOperation()
            .subscribeOn(mSingleThreadScheduler)
            .subscribe(mSubject);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not a good idea to make a method thread-safe. Because it blocks the whole method thus decrease the performance. So it is recommended to make the data structure thread-safe.
In your case your are using     **List** in your method

```
public Observable<List<Entity>> getEntities() {
```

}

Use **CopyOnWriteArrayList** instead of **List**. It is thread safe.

```
public Observable<CopyOnWriteArrayList<Entity>> getEntities() {
```

}

Hope it will work.

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect the subscribing nature of the problem, not the method call.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the relatively common use case of one observable with multiple subscribers. You need something like

```
public Observable<List<Entity>> getEntities() {
    invalidateCacheIfNeeded();
    return Observable
            .concat(cachedEntities(), networkEntities())
            .first()
            .replay(1)            
}
```

See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35951942/single-observable-with-multiple-subscribers/35952390) for
a more in depth explanation.

Comment: Looks good. A coworker also mentioned `replay()` and Publish/Subject. I'll dig into it.