# Can Publish Subject have multiple subscribers

Tags: android, rx-java, observable, rx-android

I'm trying to subscribe following function, but functions's subscribe function doesn't receive any data, but error function does. I realized that if I create second subscriber inside of function it doesn't receive data too. I was able to add multiple subscriber to subject when using Rx-JS. Is it same for Rx-Java or is there different behavior, or am I doing something completely wrong?

```
public static PublishSubject<Boolean> doSomeWork() {
    final PublishSubject<Boolean> res = PublishSubject.create();
    doSomeOtherWork().subscribe(new Consumer<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(@NonNull Boolean aBoolean) throws Exception {
                    res.onNext(true);
                }
            });

    res.subscribe(new Consumer<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(@NonNull Boolean bool) throws Exception {
        //receives data
        }
    }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(@NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
            handleSomeStuff()
                    .subscribe(new Consumer<Boolean>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(@NonNull Boolean aBoolean) throws Exception {
                            res.onNext(aBoolean);
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
    return res;

}
```

Comment: Use a `BehaviorSubject<Boolean>` instead of `PublishSubject<Boolean>`. The last value emitted, if any, and any error or completion events will be available subsequently. If you need more than the last value, you will have to use a more general `ReplaySubject`, but `BehaviorSubject` meets all my needs in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is the order in which you are doing things. You should subscribe to `res` before you subscribe to `doSomeWork()` - otherwise if `doSomeWork()` emits before the `res.subscribe(..` line, nobody is around to receive the emission.

Comment: so how I'm going to return it. Does it mean that I cannot return observable and subscribe it(function)?

Comment: Can you just `return doSomeWork()`, and subscribe to that wherever you call this method from? You can also add one (or more) `doOnNext` operators to `doSomeWork` before returning it, if you wish to `handleSomeStuff` as a side-effect. Does that make any sense?

Comment: No I can't, I'm combining multiple works and handling possible errors. Dosomework is network call, so I'm pretty sure that when onNext called, it has 2 subscribers, because they receive error event.

Comment: Hmm OK. See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35951942/single-observable-with-multiple-subscribers/35952390#35952390) can help.